local server is not being accssed by apiary
I am trying newstoolKit ,so I start the apiary on port 8090
apiary preview --path docs/api.apib --watch --port=8090 --host=0.0.0.0
and dart-frog
dart_frog dev --port 8080 --hostname 0.0.0.0
and urls like http://192.168.0.1:8080/api/v1/categories works for dart
apiary runs on http://192.168.0.1:8090/ but when I say "call resource" I get http 404 error, even though the resource is there. I am familiar with Spring/OpenAPI.

Developer tools shows me that apiary never called the local GET url, it actually calls https://jsapi.apiary.io/apis/null/http-transactions/ using POST method.

How should I get my API calls go to my actual api server, similar to swagger.
